# Adding a sub-application to an existing IIS application programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am using the `System.Web.Administration` assembly.

Using this I am able to create websites with applications and virtual directories. And the applications are able to have virtual directories.

But there doesn't seem to be an exposed way to create an application inside of an existing application.

A [Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site(v=vs.90).aspx) has an `ApplicationCollection` called `Applications`, but an [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.application(v=vs.90).aspx) does not (it only has a `VirtualDirectoryCollection`.

This seems odd to me, as it is indeed possible to create applications inside applications, at least in IIS 8.

For instance, say I wish to produce the following in IIS:

```
-> Sites
   -> mycompany.com
      -> MyApplication
         -> SubApplication
         -> SubApplication2
         -> VirtualDirectory1
```

Graphically speaking:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this using the `System.Web.Administration` framework, or do I have to go down some other deep, dark path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All *Application* are associated to a *Site* by its *path*. You can use the */* separator to create *Application* inside other *Application*.

ie:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

Site site = serverManager.Sites.Add("company.com", @"C:\tmp\company.com\www", 8080);
site.Applications.Add("/app", @"C:\tmp\company.com\app");
site.Applications.Add("/app/subApp1", @"C:\tmp\company.com\subApp1");

serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the API should be able to handle this though (by automatically picking up on the parent application's path). It would make it a lot simpler.